# import axios from axios - Parsing error: Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, axios

Any idea why I can't use axios in my React project/how to fix it?  (I can't do anything without it)

There's any other way to install environment that will support it?

I found a suggestion to add: `"parser": "babel-eslint"` to `.eslint` file - but I couldn't find this file, there're few in the `node_module` sub-folders

When trying to `import axios from axios` getting syntax error: "ESLint:
Parsing error: Unexpected token"

When used `npm install axios` I got the below:

[image]

Comment: You have an error in your import statement.  It should read: `import axios from 'axios'`

Comment:  Thank you! It's too late I guess - time to rest. Thanks again.